# What is the logical equivalence of the subtraction of two cartesian products?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove a set equivalence that involves the subtraction of two cartesian products. I have learned that the rest of sets $A-B$ can be expressed equivalently as $A \cap \overline{B}$, but what happens (or what it means) to do it for a cartesian product: $A \times B - A \times C=A \times B \cap  \overline{A \times C}$, specifically, if we negate a tuple $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ should we get $\overline{(a,b)}$ where $a \notin A$ and $b \notin B$?

Also very quick, taking the intersection of two cartesian products $(X \times Y) \cap (A \times B)$ should be equal to $(X \cap A) \times (Y \cap B)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite.   If we have an ordered pair $(x,y)$ but $(x,y)\in \overline{A\times c}$ that means that $(x,y)\not \in A\times C$ so it is not that case that *both* $x\in A$ and $y\in C$.  It does *NOT* mean that *neither* $x\in A$ nor $y \in C$. It means that *EITHER* $x\not \in A$ or $y\not \in B$ (or possibly, but not nescessarily neither).

So $\overline{A\times C}\ne \overline A\times \overline C$.  Instead $\overline{A\times C} = (\overline A\times C)\cup (A\times \overline C)\cup(\overline A\times \overline B)$.

.....

So you are correct that $(A\times B)-(A\times C) = (A\times B)\cap \overline{A\times C}$ but if we expand we get:

.....

$(A\times B)-(A\times C) = (A\times B)\cap \overline(A\times C)=$

$(A\times B) \cap [(\overline A\times C)\cup (A\times \overline C)\cup(\overline A\times \overline B)]=$

$[(A\times B)\cap(\overline A\times C)]\cup [(A\times B)\cap (A\times \overline C)]\cup [(A\times B)\cap (\overline A\times \overline C)]$.

Now it's easy to see that if if $k\in (A\times M)\cap (\overline \times N)$ for any sets $M$ and $N$ that we must have $k= (x,y)$ where $x\in A;y\in M;x\not \in A; y\in N$ and so $x\in A; x\not \in A$.  That's a contradiction so $(A\times M)\cap (\overline \times N)=\emptyset$.

So $[(A\times B)\cap(\overline A\times C)]\cup [(A\times B)\cap (A\times \overline C)]\cup [(A\times B)\cap (\overline A\times \overline C)]=(A\times B)\cap  (A\times \overline C)$

Now $k \in (A\times B)\times \overline (A\times \overline C)$ if and only if $k$ is an ordered pair so that $k=(x,y)\in (A\times B)$ and $k=(x,y)\in (A\times \overline C$ if and only if $x\in A; y\in B;y \in \overline C$ if and only if $y\in B\cap \overline C=B-C$ if and only if $(x,y)\in A\times (B-C).

So $(A\times B)-(A\times C) = (A\times B)\cap \overline{A\times C}=A\times (B-C)$.

......

But that was a very hard way to do it.

Much easier is to not that $(A\times B) -(A\times C)$ consists of the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ so that $(x,y)\in A\times B$ but that $(x,y)\not \in A\times C$.  This requires that $x\in A$ and $y$ be in $B$ but it not be the case that both $x\in A$ and $y \in C$.  In other words i) $x \in A$ ii) $y \in B$ but iii) either $x \not \in A$ or $x\not \in C$.  As we *do* have $x \in A$ we must have $y\not \in C$.

In other words i) $x \in A$ and ii) $y \in B$ and iii) $y \not \in C$ so $x\in A$ and $y \in B-C$ so $(A\times B) - (A\times C) = A\times (B-C)$.

======

As to $(X\times Y)\cap (A\times B)$:

$\{k| k\in X\times Y$ and $k\in A\times B\}=$

$\{k| k=(x,y)$ and $x\in X;y\in Y;x\in A;y\in B\}=$

$\{(x,y)|x\in X\cap A; y\in Y\cap B\}=$

$(X\cap A)\times (Y\cap B)$

.....

We can apply that to your main question.

$(A\times B)-(A\times C) =(A\times B)\cap \overline{A\times C}=$

$(A\times B) \cap [(\overline A\times C)\cup (A\times \overline C)\cup(\overline A\times \overline B)]=$

$[(A\times B)\cap(\overline A\times C)]\cup [(A\times B)\cap (A\times \overline C)]\cup [(A\times B)\cap (\overline A\times \overline C)]=$

$[(A\cap \overline A)\times (B\cap C)]\cup [(A\cap A)\times (B\cap \overline C)]\cup [(A\cap\overline A)\times (B\cap \overline C)]=$

$(\emptyset \times (B\cap C)) \cup (A\times (B-C))\cup (\emptyset\times (B-C))=$

$\emptyset \cup A\times (B-C)\cup \emptyset = A\times (B-C)$.

Comment: by the way, what a great explanation, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y) \in A \times B - A\times C$ iff $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ but **not** ($x \in A$ and $y \in C$) so iff ($x \in A$ and $x \in B-C$). So:

$$A \times B - A\times C = A \times (B-C)$$